# Spark re-triggers the map operation when doing several actions on the same RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am coding in python a machine learning task and I distribute it with spark.
I use spark 1.3.1 with python 2.7 on ubuntu (The master and one worker with 2 slots are on the same machine)

My (pseudo)code:

```
p_params = sc.parallelize(small_index_collection,numSlices=4)
eval_grid = p_params.map(highly_computational_intensive_mapper)
# in eval_grid we will have a dictionary with some numbers,
# representing various performance metrics

p1 = eval_grid.map(lambda x: x['dict_entry_1']).collect()
#Spark is lazy so basically the p1 will trigger the compute intensive mapper
p2 = eval_grid.map(lambda x: x['dict_entry_2']).collect()
p3 = eval_grid.map(lambda x: x['dict_entry_3']).collect()
p4 = eval_grid.map(lambda x: x['dict_entry_4']).collect()
......
```

I am timing each operation and p1 takes ~ the same amount of time as p2, p3. In the logs, I also see the `highly_computational_intensive_mapper` being called for each `collect()` action.

What am I doing wrong? Is the `eval_grid` RDD deleted from workers after each `collect()`? Do I have to specify some flags? Mark the RDD somehow? Do some sort of action directly on `eval_grid` before the aggregation mappers and then run the `px = ...` code on resulting RDD? What action should I use?

Thaks!

p.s. I didn't try any of the enumerated methods yet.

p.p.s. A simiar question [Why the RDD is not persisted in memory for every iteration in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924644/why-the-rdd-is-not-persisted-in-memory-for-every-iteration-in-spark) but for me, the RDD is recomputed not loaded from the disk. And of course there is no code there.

Comment: One hack is to collect on eval_grid and run the dictionary mappers in pure python. However, in time, instead of just collecting them, there will be other slightly more complicated and time consuming operations. So I need the eval_grid to be computed exactly once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `cache` on `eval_grid` so that after the first run, it is stored in memory. There is some buffer caching that should occur, but if you want true storage, then `cache`

All `eval_grid` is is a graph to show how to compute the data. Each time you call an action (`collect`) on it then it runs through that graph. `cache` short circuits that DAG and grabs the heap of data directly from memory.

Comment: 'eval_grid.chache()' right after the 2'nd line did the trick! p1 lasts ~100 seconds (small dataset for now) and the other jobs are ~0.1 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: @visoft Please don't forget to show your appreciation with an upvote and accept as the answer then :)

Comment: Yes, as soon as SO allows me to (~2-3 minutes)